# setneedsdisplay do not draw 

Tags: iphone, cgrect, setneedsdisplay

I want to repeat an image again and again.But when i run my code it crashes with a warning "MainViewController may not respond to setneedsDisplay" and also"uiviewController may not respond to initwithFrame". Here is my code.

```
  #import "MainViewController.h"


 @implementation MainViewController
 @synthesize car,road;

 UIImage *currentImage;

 int tileOffset=0;

  -(void)awakeFromNib{
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]setStatusBarHidden:YES withAnimation:NO];
[car setAlpha:0];
[road setAlpha:0];
currentImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"Road3.png"];


[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(.1) target:self selector:@selector(onTimer)
                             userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:(.01) target:self selector:@selector(onTimerRoad) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

}

 -(void)onTimerRoad{
tileOffset+=1;
[self setNeedsDisplay]; //here Get the warning
 }
 -(void)onTimer{
[self update1];

 }

 -(void)update1{

[self updateRoad];
 }
-(void)updateRoad{
[self randomRoadUpdate];
 }

-(void)randomRoadUpdate{

CGPoint oldPosition=road.center;
road.center=CGPointMake(oldPosition.x, oldPosition.y+1);

   }

 -(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame{
if(self=[super initWithFrame:frame]){//here get warning
}


return self;
 }

  -(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect{

CGImageRef image=CGImageRetain(currentImage.CGImage);
CGRect imageRect;

imageRect.origin=CGPointMake(160, 240);
imageRect.size=CGSizeMake(320, 480);

CGContextRef uicontext=UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextClipToRect(uicontext, CGRectMake(0, 0, rect.size.width, rect.size.height));
CGContextDrawTiledImage(uicontext, imageRect, image);

   }
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You are confusing a UIViewController with a UIView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

setNeedDisplays is a method for UIView.... So you need to call `[self.view setNeedDisplay]` the second warning is about your assignment statement, try this to get it out:

```
self = [super initWithFrame:frame];

if(self){
//...
}
```